# Can't sort jobs by newest when remote is checked

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

Using the following URL I can't seem to get the page to sort the list by newest even though the URL seems to be updating.

https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/remote-developer-jobs?sort=p

I use Google Chrome for Windows Version 55.0.2883.87 m

Answer (score 2):

That was a good catch, @Manuel! Thank you for the report. It should be fixed now.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the quick fix!